# Como faço pra colocar um background em um container no Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando colocar um Background em um Container alguem sabe como faz pra colocar ou alguma outra solução?
Não coloquei no Body pois a imagem precisa ficar Responsiva.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode referenciar a classe `container` e aplicar a proriedade `background`na mesma, por exemplo:

```
.container {
 background: #DDD;
}
```

Além de cor, você pode aplicar imagens responsivas, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
.container{
background-image: url(caminho da imagem);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}
```

Se atente a ordem de prioridade do seu CSS. Geralmente trabalho com o arquivo bruto do bootstrap e um CSS adicional. Com isso, mantenho o bootstrap na forma original e vou realizando as alterações em uma outra folha de estilo a qual, importo posteriormente a do bootstrap. Resumindo, meu header ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/Estilo.css">
```

Caso não tenha exatamente uma organização do CSS, o complemento `!important`, aplicado pós declaração de uma propriedade e seu valor, pode vir a ajudar. No caso, seu código poderia ficar parecido com isso:

```
.container {
 background: #DDD !important;
}
```

Comment: Ótima explicação mas segui seu exemplo e perdi toda a responsividade da imagem igual acontece com a propriedade img-responsive

Comment: Que pena! Tenta com background-size:cover;

Answer (score 2):

tenta assim:
     .container {
       background-image: url(img/sua_imagem.png);
       background-repeat:  repeat;
     }

no caso isso seria um bg de um tom uniforme, se caso for uma imagem ex: fotografia, gravura, paisagem já não serveria.
tbm nao se esqueça do !important ao final dos atributos

Comment: o que o !important faz ?

Comment: O !important sobrescreve o valor definido para a mesma propriedade em outro lugar do código. Ou seja, se na div class teste o color é red e depois na div class teste em outro lugar do código o color é blue, você consegue definir com o !important qual dos dois será o valor prioritário para a propriedade em questão

Comment: ele força a regra, para que ela seja aceita na interpretação do browser

Answer (score 1):

experimente:

```
background-image: url("caminho da imagem"); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```